# Laurent Series of $f(z)=\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ about $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

To expand $f(z)=\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ about $z=0$? can someone do a step by step explained method please?

Comment: First off, what's the Taylor expansion of $\sin(x)$ at $x=0$?  Then let $x\to1/z$ and you should have your answer.

Comment: But if I want to do it about z=0 and you use x=1/z then surely isn't that around x=infinity?

Comment: Recall that you can have $1/x$ in the Laurent series of a function about $x=0$, so you needn't do anything at $\infty$.

Comment: I don't doubt you are correct, the problem is my understanding right now. I thought using a Taylor series approach, $sin(x)$ around x=0 goes to $sin(0) + cos(0)x -sin(0)\frac{x^2}{2!} - cos(0)\frac{x^3}{3!}...$
Using this logic when I try around z=0 for $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ goes to $sin(\frac{1}{0}) -cos(\frac{1}{0})\frac{1}{z} ...$ the problem here is evaluating sin(\frac{1}{0})? easy for sin(0) but this is where I am struggling to understand why a simple substitution would work with z=0 would mean x=infinity

Comment: Yes, we have: $$\sin(x)=x-\frac1{3!}x^3+\frac1{5!}x^5-\frac1{7!}x^7+\dots$$ and as I said, let $x\to1/z$

Comment: Yes and the coefficients about x=0:
f'(0) + f'''(0) + f'''''(0) + ....

Comment: Yes, but you forgot the question.  I have given you $\sin(x)$.  Now let $x\to1/z$.

Comment: so if $x \rightarrow \frac{1}{z}$ around x=0 the expansion is what is given above.
But if x=0 then z is infinite and doing the expansion with the z without a substitution gives infinite coefficients

Comment: Show me the result after letting $x\to1/z$ and then explain to me what it means to have a Laurent series about $z=0$.

Comment: If we are to expand around a point and you chose a substitution so expand around another point how does the substitution just get inserted back without any change of any coefficients?

Comment: You still haven't shown me the result after letting $x\to1/z$.  Then we can talk.

Comment: $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ around z=0, let $x=\frac{1}{z}$ so now expand $sin(x)$ around $x=\frac{1}{0}$
I'm not sure I know how to do that...

Comment: Please look above.  I have given you a series form of $\sin(x)$.  I merely ask you to let $x\to1/z$.  Nothing about $z=0$ or $x=0$ yet.  Just $x\to1/z$

Comment: I understand and I agree if we have:
$sin(x) = x - \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{1}{5!}x^5 - \frac{1}{7!}x^7$
and substitute $x=\frac{1}{z}$ then we get:
$sin(\frac{1}{z}) = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{3!}(\frac{1}{z})^3 + \frac{1}{5!}(\frac{1}{z})^5 - \frac{1}{7!}(\frac{1}{z})^7$

Comment: Now is that a Laurent series about $z=0$?

Comment: I personally don't think so no, but it is?

Comment: Looks like a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) from the definition of a Laurent series to me.

Comment: [Looks centered at zero, does it not?](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sdsfnbyuax)  In the sense of a Laurent series of course.

Comment: Ok so, is this the only way to do it or could you use a different method?
maybe using $f(z) =\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n$ where $a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z) \,dz}{(z-c)^{n+1}} $ or $a_n = \frac{1}{n!} f^n(z_0)$?

Comment: $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$ for Taylor series, when you can't have $a_{-1}$ or $a_{-k}$.  Indeed, this is the most direct approach.

Comment: so you cant solve with the direct approach?

Comment: You can, but how would you compute those integrals?

Comment: I don't think I could, which is why I asked for an explanation in the first place

Comment: Indeed, the problem is usually worked the other way.  Compute the integral by using the series.

Comment: I appreciate your help but you haven't quite explained it in a helpful useful way here and I am still struggling to understand why it's ok. I'm not doubting it's right I'm just struggling to understand why it's right.

Comment: Well, what are you still struggling with?  I think your problem lies between what a Laurent series really is and what it means for a Laurent series to be centered at a point means.

Comment: I think you are correct there, my understanding of what it means to be centred at a point is poor and I must go away and read up on quite a bit.

Comment: So, knowing that at the point, the function is not analytic, therefore we can not use Taylor series and so we use Laurent. But I still don't understand why we can use the Maclaurin then just substitute what we have in?

Comment: Because the resulting series is one with terms of the form $a_n(z-0)^n$ with $n\in\mathbb Z$ and coefficients $a_n$.

Comment: And so the constant has no dependence on the variable so a simple substitution is ok?

Comment: Yes,  that is correct.